# control spacing and sizing of submatrices

Tags: matrices

How can I reproduce this matrix?

[image]

my attempt so far :

```
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix} C_N \end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix} \\ \boldsymbol{k} \\ \end{bmatrix} \\
    \begin{bmatrix}& \boldsymbol{k}^T & \end{bmatrix} & \kappa
\end{bmatrix}
```

yields something less symmetrical:

[image]

Comment: I would only use straight separators instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use stacks, with some `\makebox`es to pad the horizontal width, `\addstackgap` to pad the vertical height, and a `\vcenter` to get it all vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,eulervm}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\left[\vcenter{\hbox{\addstackgap[1pt]{%
\stackanchor{\Biggl[\makebox[10ex]{$C_N$}\Biggr]
\Biggl[\makebox[3ex]{$k$}\Biggr]}
{\bigl[\makebox[10ex]{$k^T$}\bigr]~
\bigl[\makebox[3ex]{$\kappa$}\bigr]}}}}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nested matrices; the trick is to add some big invisible object:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \makebox[4em]{$\Bigg.C_{N}$} \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} \makebox[1em]{$\Bigg.\mathbf{k}$} \end{bmatrix}
\\[3.5ex]
\begin{bmatrix} \makebox[4em]{$\mathbf{k}^T$} \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} \makebox[1em]{$k$} \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution with the `blkarray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, blkarray}

\begin{document}

{\boldmath \[ \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{blockarray}{cccc}
    \begin{block}{[ccc][c]}
    & & & \\
    & C_N & & \boldsymbol{k} \\
    & & &\\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{[ccc][c]}
    & k^T & & \kappa \\
    \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\vspace*{-1.8ex}
\end{bmatrix}
\]}%

\end{document}
```

[image]